# Latest version of parrot security os?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, parrot-os

I recently updated my  parrot security os and it got upgraded to version 3.5 cyberGalleon. But in the parrot website downloads the latest version is 3.4.1. is the 3.5 cyberGalleon with kernel 4.9.0 the upcoming version?

[image]

Comment: This question isn’t very suitable for Super User, because it will go out of date quickly. Why not ask on [Parrot’s forums](https://community.parrotsec.org/)?

Comment: @Daniel B I asked in the forum , only got views no answer or comment.

Comment: You probably should check whatever update channel it's using as the official source and look at when and by whom (if possible) it was updated. As it seems to be a Debian variant you should check your sources file.

Comment: Parrot Security OS 3.5 is currently being tested based on my research.  Parrot Security OS 3.4.1 is the last stable release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parrot is a rolling release distribution, and version numbers are just "tags" assigned to "particular snapshots" of the repository used to build updated versions of the ISO files.

your situation is caused by the fact that you did a full upgrade through the apt repository and you got the latest version of every package, while the ISO files on the website were not rebuilt yet

according to the official projet's blog (https://blog.parrotsec.org/parrot-3-5-release-date/) the new ISO files will be released in March 8 2017